GoException no routes for location using "url_launcher" on Flutter
I am using url_launcher: 6.3.0 in my app, without any direct usage of go_router plugin in it. The code I am using to open a link is:
Future<void> _launchUrl(Uri url) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(url = url,
        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication, webOnlyWindowName: '_blank')) {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }

The urls are on static Github pages (no Jekyll, just plain HTML), with a structure like this example https://myuser.github.io/myapp/help.html. The pages are normally accessible via browser.
My AndroidManifest.xml includes this configuration:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

If I try to access to any external url like https://google.com, it works fine but if I try to access to links from Github, like in the link above, it will return the error:

GoException: no routes for location: https://.....

How can I fix that?
